# Why not name "Gardening and Landscaping" as "Horticulture" Instead?

Tags: discussion

I noticed many of the other stack exchanges are based on scientific disciplines and horticulture certainly encompasses both gardening and landscaping with some added produce farming and science. Thoughts?

Comment: I disagree @Rhizoqueer  What a moniker!  Horticulture is very limited.  It is all about growing plants, period.  Landscape is a whole 'nuther creature.  Horticulture is but a tiny tiny part of Landscape, critical for sure but people  who wanto have success outside of their homes need far more than how to grow a plant.  Landscape includes, well, I can't think of a science that is not included in Landscape Architecture.  Mechanics; irrigation, 2 stroke mowers and other equipment.  Electrical; lighting, irrigation and timers.  Astronomy perhaps?  Physics; light energy, the attenuation of light.

Comment: ...Hydrology, weather, climate, agriculture, politics!  Art, composition, interior design for exterior spaces.  What people learn here is we live within a web, a huge web of genres and if one misses out on a particular genre they will be unsuccessful.  It is also humbling.  Unlike other sites, this one demonstrates the big picture.  There are no simple answers.  Well, I prove that, others know how to do straight forward answers.  I am still learning to compartmentalize!

Answer (score 7):

When I took courses it was called Horticulture or Arboriculture or Soil Science.  However many of the questions posted here are from users with no formal training or education in Horticulture.

I think Stack Exchange and the title of this exchange try to be inclusive to as many types of users as possible.  By using a title associated with professional study or work users may not feel this exchange is right for them.

Comment: That makes sense.I just saw sites like Biology and Chemistry and they seemed successful. The name seemed like it could be more impacting. :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe people searching for gardening advice don't know that what they're looking for is on the Horticulture site. I'll soon be a Horticulture graduate and my friends still ask me what is this about.

Answer (score 2):

I'd hate to change the name to just Gardening (Horticulture is just too unknown or too scary a word).  Landscaping should probably be an entirely separate site.  Plants and gardening are the smallest part of this profession.  I kid you not.  A Landscape Architect is taught to have the capacity to see a  humongous picture and know a little about a lot of genres.  Maybe a lot about a lot.  It is huge.  Landscape Architecture is fairly unknown by most.  Confused with landscape designers, arborists, gardening, construction...on and on.  So very different than just gardening and plants. That is like an Interior designer having to deal with just couches or fireplaces or flooring.  To become a Landscape Architect takes 4 days of serious testing.  Similar to passing the bar for lawyers or getting through the medical system's need to have sleepless doctors in the emergency rooms.  The list of skills and systems one has to be able to be proficient is mind boggling.  I can't think of a single thing a Landscape Architect need not be concerned or educated about.  I'd say color in your living room but that is relevant as well.  Perhaps two sites where the questioner is able to be directed to the proper site and assisted in phrasing their question/needs at the very beginning would be helpful.  I know, but this solution just screams to me to keep harping.  Just a simple questionaire for the OP that in essence narrows down choices and facilitates a quicker turn around?

Comment: If we didn't add landscaping we'd have even fewer posts!

Comment: Oh I agree, Graham.  Once there is an OP in our web we need to make a positive experience.  Having simple questions to focus their question and actually lead them to offer more information...I think this would be more satisfying for everyone.

Comment: Landscaping doesnt always include gardening which is an irony to the common combination.

Comment: Most people don't use horticulture in the search engines.Gardening on the other hand is the first thing people will look for.  Landscaping is very broad to include most everything related to people's yards. Sort of the big picture.  Gardening and Landscaping offers a larger scope and it is more user friendly.  I'd like to see more people asking questions under Landscaping, like the more permanent and expensive garden work that changes the value of ones property in a big way.